# jQuery - Set and reset a transition delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, settimeout

- I am triggering a transition animation by adding an active class.
- At the end of the animation I remove the active class **(after a
  delay)** so it can be triggered again.

This works beautifully on the first iteration but subsequent iterations and clicking the `close` function does not reset the delay count.

The timeout timer obviously needs clearing or resetting on each click but I am unable to get this to work consistantly. I have been trying to use `clearTimeout()` function.

```js
$("#btn").on('click', function() {
  $("#msg").prop("class", "alert active");
  removeActive();
});

function removeActive() {
  $("#msg").on("transitionend", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#msg").removeClass("active");
    }, 3000)
  });
}

$("#close").on("click", function() {
  $("#msg").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.alert {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: -100px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
  background: #3dc0f1;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  z-index: 10;
}

.alert.active {
  bottom: 20px;
}

#msg-tx {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
}

#close {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" type="submit">Go</button>

<div id="msg" class="alert">
  <p id="msg-tx">Hello There</p>
  <div id="close">X</div>
</div>
```

Click the Go button several times to cause the timeout to become inconsistant.

Comment: Why the `3000)` ?

Comment: Don't use `$("#msg").prop("class", "alert active");` you might stash erratically other classes assigned (current or future) to that element.

Comment: `.addClass()` , `.removeClass()`, `.toggleClass()` ... those operate on a specific className/s - not on the entire string of the `class` attribute.

Comment: Why `clearTimeout` not work in your case? How did you use it?

Comment: Why `$("#msg").off()` what event listener you need to off on the `#msg` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a variable to keep the timeout and clear it when you set new timeout.

Example:

```js
var timeout;

$("#btn").on('click', function() {
  $("#msg").addClass("alert active");
  removeActive();
});

function removeActive() {
  $("#msg").on("transitionend", function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      $("#msg").removeClass("active");
    }, 3000);
  });
}

$("#close").on("click", function() {
  $("#msg").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.alert {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: -100px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
  background: #3dc0f1;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  z-index: 10;
}

.alert.active {
  bottom: 20px;
}

#msg-tx {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
}

#close {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" type="submit">Go</button>

<div id="msg" class="alert">
  <p id="msg-tx">Hello There</p>
  <div id="close">X</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This was close to what I was trying with `clearTimeout()` I now see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Rely on the CSS delay by animating another property (translate in this case) and make the jQuery code easier.

```js
$("#btn").on('click', function() {
  $("#msg").removeClass("active");
  setTimeout(function() {      
    $("#msg").addClass("active");
   }, 200)
});

$("#close").on("click", function() {
  $("#msg").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.alert {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: -100px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
  background: #3dc0f1;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.2s;
  z-index: 10;
}

.alert.active {
  bottom: 20px;
  transform:translateY(calc(100% + 40px));
  transition: bottom ease-in-out 0.3s,transform 0.3s 3s;
}

#msg-tx {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
}

#close {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" type="submit">Go</button>

<div id="msg" class="alert">
  <p id="msg-tx">Hello There</p>
  <div id="close">X</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is beautiful and pure. Thanks.

Comment: This has the small drawback of needing to know the size of the `msg` element which is dynamic in this case.

Comment: @DreamTeK check the update, simply rely on percentage to cover the full height of the element + the needed offset.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the timeout is being added on `transitionend` - remove this and it all works fine (possibly adjust the timeout to compensate).

Why does this occur: consider:

1. click to add class alert starts transition
2. transition end removes active to start moving it back down
3. transition end (moved down) occurs and kicks in the timeout again
4. click to add class active
5. previous timeout kicks in and removes active 3 seconds after it finished moving down (step 3) before 3 seconds are up for step 4

```js
$("#btn").off().on('click', function() {
  $("#msg").prop("class", "alert active");
  removeActive();
});

function removeActive() {
  //$("#msg").off().on("transitionend", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#msg").removeClass("active");
    }, 3000)
  //});
}

$("#close").off().on("click", function() {
  $("#msg").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.alert {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: -100px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
  background: #3dc0f1;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.alert.active {
  bottom: 20px;
}

#msg-tx {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
}

#close {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" type="submit">Go</button>

<div id="msg" class="alert">
  <p id="msg-tx">Hello There</p>
  <div id="close">X</div>
</div>
```

Alternatives:

- remove the transitionend handler in the setTimeout
- use .once instead of .on (may have similar problems if clicking before completed)

Comment: Thanks for this however your example does not fix the issue. Both clicking the `Go` button several times or click close messes up the timer.

Comment: You are right however that the transitionend is surplus to requirements.